# Is it require to Rebuild NonClustered Index on MS sql server on Time interval

Tags: sql-server, indexing, rebuild

Database : MS SQL Server 2008 R2 or higher

I have one table with more than a million records.
Clustered and NonClustered index create on this table.
Daily around 1000-1500 records added in same table, after this report generate daily on this data.

Do I have to rebuild non clustered index after insert records and before generate the reports?
OR
rebuild index On weekly basis?

So that report output comes quickly

Comment: I would say you have to understand the pattern first. Check the performance when you build your index weekly and when you daily. The other part which needs to understand do you have sufficient maintenance window or not.

Comment: Thanks Rajat, I will check it on test server. but i dint get you on maintenance window?

Comment: If your data is live then depends upon the data size and user load index rebuild might take time.so the best way to rebuild the index when there is no or less user load. which we can say maintenance window.

Comment: Thanks Again Rajat, I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it required?

No, but it's highly recommended to keep an eye on fragmentation levels. The more operations (inserts, deletes and updates) you do on columns that are part of the index or included in them, the more likely it is to raise fragmentation.

Having fragmented indexes will impact on performance at certain thresholds. As Rajat mentioned, the challenge relies on knowing how often you need to rebuild them and when. The timing depends on your weekly, daily or even hour by hour workload and the size of your tables. How often to do it will depend on the amount of operations done at the records and the performance requirements you have.

Comment: Thanks Ezlo for your answer in detail